# Program crashes when I assign a scanner object to a variable

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a program that reads a date input in the form `month/day/year`. Unfortunately, I am currently stuck at the statement `int year = dateScan.nextInt();`. When I run my program, it crashes on that line. However, if I remove that entire statement and change `System.out.println("year: " + year);` to `System.out.println("year: " + dateScan());` , The program does not crash. My concern is I need the variable year to print the whole date, so the print statement `System.out.println("\nThe date is: " + monthName + " " + day + "," + year);` at the end will work. I need to know why it crashes on that line. Thank you!

public class DateFormat {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); // define a Scanner object attached to the keyboard
    System.out.print("Enter a date in the form month/day/year: "); // prompt user for input
    String inputString = keyboard.nextLine(); // read entire input line as a String

    Scanner dateScan = new Scanner (inputString); // define a Scanner object attached to a String

    // set the Scanner's delimiter to "zero or more spaces followed by a slash (/) followed by zero or more spaces"
    dateScan.useDelimiter("\\s*/\\s*"); 

    int month = dateScan.nextInt();
    if ( ! dateScan.hasNextInt()) // is the first input value an int?
    {
        String badInput = dateScan.next();
        System.out.println("Error: expected an integer, encountered: " + badInput);
        System.out.print("Try again later...");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("month: " + month); // safe to read first input value

    int day = dateScan.nextInt();
    if ( ! dateScan.hasNextInt()) // is the next input value an int?
    {
        String badInput = dateScan.next();
        System.out.println("Error: expected an integer, encountered: " + badInput);
        System.out.print("Try again later...");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("day: " + day); // safe to read next input value

    int year = dateScan.nextInt();
    if ( ! dateScan.hasNextInt()) // is the next input value an int?
    {
        String badInput = dateScan.next();
        System.out.println("Error: expected an integer, encountered: " + badInput);
        System.out.print("Try again later...");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("year: " + year); // safe to read next input value

    // the user entered an integer
    String monthName = "Unknown month name";
    switch(month)
{
        case 1: monthName = "January"; break;
        case 2: monthName = "February"; break;
        case 3: monthName = "March"; break;
        case 4: monthName = "April"; break;
        case 5: monthName = "May"; break;
        case 6: monthName = "June"; break;
        case 7: monthName = "July"; break;
        case 8: monthName = "August"; break;
        case 9: monthName = "September"; break;
        case 10: monthName = "October"; break;
        case 11: monthName = "November"; break;
        case 12: monthName = "December"; break;                           
}
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        System.out.println("Error: " + month + " is an invalid month value");
    else
        System.out.println("\nThe date is: " + monthName + " " + day + "," + year);      
}
```

}

Comment: You need to check `hasNextInt` *before* you call `nextInt` to actually get that int.

Comment: `dateScan` is a reference, you can't access it like a method `dateScan()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
    int year = dateScan.nextInt();
    if ( !dateScan.hasNextInt()) // is the next input value an int?
```

to

```
    int year = dateScan.nextInt();
    if ( dateScan.hasNextInt()) // is the next input value an int?
```

The error happens since you are checking this: `dateScan.hasNextInt()` and since dateScan has no next element you are doing

```
String badInput = dateScan.next()
```

which causes exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: I did not expect to get an answer right away. I changed it and it worked. Thanks! But can you please elaborate on "since dateScan has no next element"? I'm still new to java and programming in general so terms really do confuse me. Another question -- How come the if ( !dateScan.hasNextInt()) work fine with the month and day variables, but not the year variable?

Comment: You are using dateScan to iterate over date fields. Since year is last field, you take it out with int year = dateScan.nextInt() so if ( !dateScan.hasNextInt()) returns true, but you don't have any more fields in the iterator, so String badInput = dateScan.next(); causes exception.

Comment: You've been such a great help, but I still got more questions. Hope you don't mind. I just noticed that the statement block after the if statement stopped working after I assigned dateScan.nextInt() to month, day and year.  It just crashes instead of printing badInput. If I revert it to the original (removing month, day, year variables and just print dateScan.nextInt(), the statement block works and it prints badInput (data types other than int). My questions are why does it crash and how am I supposed to assign those values to those 3 variables and be able to print them together like a date?

Comment: Basically, the purpose of the if statements is to detect user inputs that aren't integers and prints them, so the program won't crash.  But now, it crashes if I type a non-integer input.

Comment: hey i fixed it now don't worry. I didn't remove the month day year variables but placed them after each of their corresponding badInput statement block instead. I also changed back the condition for the year to !dateScan.hasNextInt();